# JQuery UI Autocomplete Combobox highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a `<select>` which I need to transform in more functional combobox.

```
<span class="combo_box">
    <select id="state" name="state" tabindex="24">
        <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none"></option>
        <!-- Some JSP here -->
    </select>
</span>
```

And I transformed it in to widget (so original `<select>` with id "state" is still there but hidden) like this `$("#state").combobox();` What i need is to add an error highlight to this custom widget on form submission if combobox is empty. jQuery UI has a custom CSS class `ui-state-error` for this.

Validation script (works fine as I debug it)

```
function setComboboxClassBeforeSubmit(elementID) {
    var flag = true;
    var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
    var combobox = $(element).combobox();
    combobox.removeClass('ui-state-error');
    if (isEmpty(element)) {
        combobox.addClass('ui-state-error');
        flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

But adding this CSS class seems like have no effect on widget look. Also tried hardcode like it was shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998772/jquery-ui-calling-highlight-error), something like `$("#state").addClass('ui-state-error')` and still no luck.
Also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055626/how-to-addclassui-state-error-to-a-select-styled-with-selectmenu-dropkick), works fine for selectmenu but not for combobox.

**Possible solution:** (thanks to [nowhere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2042240/nowhere))

Editing `_createAutocomplete: function()` like this:

```
_createAutocomplete: function() {
            var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

        this.input = $( "<input>" )
            .appendTo( this.wrapper )
            .val( value )
            .attr( "title", "" )
            .attr( "id", "ui-" + this.element.attr("id") + "-input" )
...
```

Issue is - default API doesn't generate unique ID's for combobox's elements.

Comment: Are you sure you're not applying the class to the hidden select? :P

Comment: @nowhere that is the core of the problem, in the working solution I mentioned they used some generated id's for widget elements. But i didn't found id's for combobox elements (autocomplete and button).

Comment: Also: to my knowledge style="display:none" doesn't work in every browser when added to options. Have you tried it with older versions of IE?

Comment: This solution is for specific browser and for specific customer so no issue with that.

Comment: you need to identify the select created by the widget somehow... can't you rely on any class or id? Does it have a parent element you can use to identify it?

Comment: Maybe it might be useful if you post the html code generated by the widget. (just the new select it creates and the parent element)

Comment: Widget generated like it described in [this](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) documentation under the source section, there i can see class applying, but no id applying, class is to general because i have many comboboxes on page.

Comment: @nowhere so if I'll use it like `$(".custom-combobox-input").addClass('ui-state-error')` it will work, but it will highlight all my  comboboxes, not the specific one.

Comment: so you have multiple comboboxes? In this case my answer might not work...

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with the code I've made here? I operated by using the jqueryui example: http://jsfiddle.net/b5e83x2q/

```js
function checkValue(item){
    item.removeClass('ui-state-error');
    if(item.val()==""){
        item.addClass('ui-state-error');
    }
}

checkValue($(".custom-combobox input"));
```

```css
.ui-state-error{
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="custom-combobox">
    <input title="" class="custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" value="">
</span>
```

EDIT:

if you need to identify a specific select you should give it a specific id: if you used the same code of the jqueryui example you should have:

```
  _create: function() {
    this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
      .insertAfter( this.element );

    this.element.hide();
    this._createAutocomplete();
    this._createShowAllButton();
  }
```

there you might try to add something like:

**`this.attr('id', 'specificId');`**

or edit the span wrapper:

```
_create: function() {
    this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
      .insertAfter( this.element )
      .attr('id', 'specificId');

    this.element.hide();
    this._createAutocomplete();
    this._createShowAllButton();
  }
```

After that you can use:

```
checkValue($("#specificId input"));
```

to change only 1 select.

Comment: Problem is if I have multiple selects with this class all of them will be highlighted. So I need to extract id of specific combobox input and specific combobox button.

Comment: @Ahnassi Yes but if you add an id to it via code you should be able to access the element you want. Have you tried my code after the "edit" part?

Comment: Thank you! Editing `_create: function()` worked great though i don't think changing API is a very good solution but the best one i have for now.

Comment: @Ahnassi Well we're just going around it's limits to make it better :P Glad to be of some help.